# Using spritesheets failed when trying to load an image

Tags: python, image, pygame, load, sprite

I am making a little game to practice programming in pygame. I have come around an error when I try to use a spritesheet. I was trying to fix it but I don't see what the problem is.

```
class Spritesheet:
    # loading and parsing spritesheets

    def __init__(self, filename,game):
        self.spritesheet = pygame.image.load(filename).convert()

    def get_image(self, x, y, width, height):
        # take an image from the spritesheet
        image = pygame.Surface((width,height))
        image.blit(self.spritesheet, (0,0), (x, y, width, height))
        return image
```

This is the class. The next one is the load data function within my game class

```
    def load_data(self):
        # ------------- load --------------
        self.dir = path.dirname(__file__)
        img_dir = path.join(self.dir, 'img')

        # load the spritesheet
        self.spritesheet = Spritesheet(path.join(img_dir, SPRITESHEET))
```

`SPRITESHEET` is defined seperately in the settings file. Here I call the function and try to get the image from it. Here is where I get the error.

```
    def __init__(self,game):

        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        # use surface to create image
        self.game = game
        self.image = self.game.spritesheet.get_image(614,1063,120,191)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(x=50, y=399 )
```

Error message: `self.image = self.game.spritesheet.get_image(614,1063,120,191)
AttributeError: 'Game' object has no attribute 'spritesheet'`

Here's the complete project: https://github.com/Frago23/Frago1321

Comment: Put the content here, not through external links.

Comment: Do not post code as images.

Comment: where do you run `def __init__(self,game):` ? Maybe you run it before you run `load_data(self):` - and then `spritesheet` doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Please always provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I could only find the error because I looked at your github repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never call the `load_data` method in your `Game` class, so you never load the spritesheet and the game instance won't have a `self.spritesheet` attribute. Just call it in the `__init__` method of the `Game` class and it should work (as long as there are no other issues).

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem